# How to use systemproperties to get property by using Spring EL and @Value()

Tags: spring

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public CompactDisc cd(@Value("#{ systemProperties['artist']}") String artist) {
       HotelCalifornia hotelCalifornia = new HotelCalifornia();
        hotelCalifornia.setArtist( artist);
        return hotelCalifornia;
    }

    @Bean
    public CdPlayer player(CompactDisc cd) {
        CdPlayer player = new CdPlayer();
        player.setCd(cd);
        return player;
    }
}
```

The property is in the test.properties file. I cant get the property "artist" from the systemProperties.But I can get it if i use @autowired to instantiate a environment bean.How can i deal with it?

Comment: Is it in the system properties (`-Dname=value`), the environment (`export name=value`) or in the `test.properties` file?

Comment: In the test.properties file.

Comment: Well that's not `systemProperties`, which is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to do anything. the spring recognizes property is first it will check in the system properties, then the class level properties and then properties initialized using property placeholder.

so try using `@Value("${artist}")` provided you have artist set in the systems property somehow.